# ASP.NET List<SelectListItem> is passing null to controller

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form, with radiobuttons. After selecting one of them, in [POST] method, the 'Companies' List Count is still 0. Do you have any idea what causes the problem?

Controller:

```
    // GET: Commission/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        CommissionMVCCreateModel commission = new CommissionMVCCreateModel();

        List<CompanyMVCModel> companies = SQLiteDataAccess.LoadCompanies();
        commission.Companies = companies.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.CompanyName, Value = x.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
        return View(commission);
    }

    // POST: Commission/Create
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CommissionMVCCreateModel commissionModel)
    {
        try
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }

            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
    public class CommissionMVCCreateModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Companies { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();
...
...
}
```

View:

```
<form>
...
...
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Companies, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="btn-group-vertical">

      @foreach (var company in Model.Companies) 
      {

          <label class="btn btn-primary col-md-offset-2 col-md-5 ">
                                                                                        
              <input type="radio" name="company" id="@company.Value" value="@company.Value"/>
              @company.Text
                                               
          </label> 
      }
    </div>
...
...
</form>
```

In the form i have also part for creating new Company, and it's values are passed correctly. The only problem i have is with this SelectListItem. I tried also using SelectList, but the result was the same.

Comment: any debug window errors during model binding?. Your model has name `companies`, but ui has a name as `company`

Comment: You should have an `public int company { get; set; }` in the `CommissionMVCCreateModel` model.

Comment: @Saravanan there aren't any errors due to model binding, replaced checkbox name but it didn;t solve the problem

Comment: @VDWWD Why so? Im loading list of companies <CompanyMVCModel> from DB, and in controller, i'm filling it with 'Id' of company and it's name. So i have already an id of company, but it's nested within it's Model

Comment: Your model binding works by name in the input elements to be mapped to the property in the object model. Incase you want to bind from company to the list of objects, you should have a custom model binder